# Bootstrap Popover on hover - Middle of content not working correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to center my bootstrap popover in the div. Like this way.

[image]

I tried and it worked fine but there is a problem. When you hover from **right side** which is popover visible, it will flicker more time.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7d38fmL/)

here is my code

```
<div class="bs-example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Default popover">Popover 1</button>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    placement: 'right',
    trigger: 'hover',
    width: '500px'
  });
});

.bs-example {
     margin: 50px 50px;
}

.popover-content {
    padding: 2px 10px;
}

.popover.right>.arrow{
  display: none;
}

.popover{
   left: 90px!important;
   top: 53px!important;
}
```

Tried more time and still couldn't fine solution. Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `pointer-events: none;`

```
.popover{
   left: 90px!important;
   top: 53px!important;
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

[#### Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/wzf9ndp3/3/)

Answer (score 0):

flicker issue will stay till you have popover overlap the button. you have to change the position of popover.

What happen on first hover you popover shows and then you loose the focus from button so popover closed and this will happen in loop.

Answer (score -1):

Please remove the `left` attribute from `popover` CSS

`.popover{
   top: 53px!important;
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/q4joduzc/1/